# Get arguments from another component [React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a web-app using React. I'm facing a problem with my navbar and the main content:

In **AppWrapper** I have this:

```
var contents = [
   <Offers />,
   <Create />,
   <List />
];
```

and where each item will be the content displaying.

In getInitialState I initialize it like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    currentTab: 0
  };
},
```

Later, in render function I have this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <div className='mainPanel'>
      {contents[this.state.currentTab]}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

You can see that I call the navbar component before the content.

In **Navbar** component I have a menu where, from there, I want to change the currentTab of **AppWrapper**.

How can I do that? Thank you for advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to handle it, I found how to do that.

This is the answer:

```
<Navbar selectTab={this.selectTab} />

selectTab: function(tab) {
    this.setState({ currentTab: tab });
}
```

I pass to **Navbar** component the function "selectTab of the parent (**AppWrapper**).

Then in Navbar component:

```
<li>
    <a onClick={this.selectTab.bind(this, 0)}><i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw" /> Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a onClick={this.selectTab.bind(this, 1)}><i className="fa fa-edit fa-fw" /> Create</a>
</li>
```

Then in selectTab of **Navbar** I change the props to current tab.

```
selectTab: function(tab) {
    this.props.selectTab(tab);
},
```

Hope someone helps this answer!